# How can I get SF Symbols components?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation, sf-symbols

I would like to get the components of an SF Symbol so that I can then animate it, with animations on the individual components.

Is it possible?

For example, in the photo below I would like to separate the raindrops from the cloud.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Export it as SVG and change anything you want. Also, please read license first, I am not sure if it's allowed to update or not.

Comment: From [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/sf-symbols) _To help you identify a noncustomizable symbol, the SF Symbols app badges it with an Info icon; to help you use the symbol correctly, the inspector pane describes its usage restrictions._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible! ✨

SF Symbols is an iconography library integrated with the system font for Apple platforms.

You can export and edit the symbols that you want using vector graphics editing tools to create yours.

Here's a link where you can read more about it 
https://glyphsapp.com/learn/creating-an-sf-symbol